# How to perform arithmetic operation on the outputs of 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below are 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(BUG.BG_BUG_ID) AS BUG_ID_SIT_CNT 
FROM BUG 
WHERE BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'SIT'

SELECT COUNT(BUG.BG_BUG_ID) AS BUG_ID_UAT_CNT 
FROM BUG 
WHERE BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'UAT'
```

How to write a query to use the results from the above queries and perform the below operation:

Defect Removal Efficiency: `BUG_ID_SIT_CNT/(BUG_ID_SIT_CNT + BUG_ID_UAT_CNT)`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT BUG_ID_SIT_CNT * 1. / BUG_ID_ALL
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN BG_USER_02 = 'SIT' THEN BG_BUG_ID END) AS BUG_ID_SIT_CNT,
        COUNT(BG_BUG_ID) AS BUG_ID_ALL
    FROM BUG
    WHERE BG_USER_02 IN ('SIT', 'UAT')
) t
```

Comment: Do you really need that `WHERE` condition?

Comment: Yes - if we have index on this column

Comment: Can you please explain what this function does? BUG_ID_SIT_CNT * 1.

Comment: Implicit conversion to float, because `COUNT` always return result as `INT`. For example: `SELECT 1 / 3 = 0` and `SELECT 1. / 3 = 0.333333`. Check my post about this - http://blog.devart.com/fastest_way_to_calculate_the_record_count.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This query worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can get it in a outer query like

```
SELECT BUG_ID_SIT_CNT/(BUG_ID_SIT_CNT + BUG_ID_UAT_CNT) as testcol
FROM (
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'SIT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BUG_ID_SIT_CNT,
SUM(CASE WHEN BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'UAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BUG_ID_UAT_CNT 
FROM BUG ) xx;
```

Comment: Using `SUM` instead of `COUNT` is a bad practice. Please check my post - http://blog.devart.com/what-is-faster-inside-stream-aggregate-hash-match.html

Comment: Thanks for this query. Just one problem the output is returning 0. The addition operation is returning the correct value. But when division is performed the output becomes 0. Can you please help out with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap both querys in a WITH statement and than perform the calculations in your SELECT.

Comment: He tagged his question with sql server, not MySQL.

Comment: Actually, it was tagged MySQL too until a later edit, but now you're quite correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sit
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(BUG.BG_BUG_ID) AS BUG_ID_SIT_CNT 
    FROM BUG 
    WHERE BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'SIT'
),
uat
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(BUG.BG_BUG_ID) AS BUG_ID_UAT_CNT 
    FROM BUG 
    WHERE BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'UAT'
)
SELECT sit.BUG_ID_SIT_CNT/(sit.BUG_ID_SIT_CNT + uat.BUG_ID_UAT_CNT) 
FROM sit, uat
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with parameters as I find this more readable:

```
DECLARE @BUG_ID_SIT_CNT AS INT = 
(SELECT COUNT(BUG.BG_BUG_ID)
FROM BUG 
WHERE BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'SIT')

DECLARE @BUG_ID_UAT_CNT AS INT =
(SELECT COUNT(BUG.BG_BUG_ID)
FROM BUG 
WHERE BUG.BG_USER_02 = 'UAT')

SELECT @BUG_ID_SIT_CNT/(@BUG_ID_SIT_CNT + @BUG_ID_UAT_CNT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(BUG_ID_SIT_CNT as decimal) / cast((BUG_ID_SIT_CNT + BUG_ID_UAT_CNT)as decimal) 
FROM (
 SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN BG_USER_02 = 'SIT' THEN BG_BUG_ID END) AS BUG_ID_SIT_CNT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN BG_USER_02 = 'UAT' THEN BG_BUG_ID END) AS BUG_ID_UAT_CNT
FROM BUG
WHERE BG_USER_02 IN ('SIT', 'UAT')
) t
```